# Ajuda com paginas do app!

Tags: c#, android, angularjs, ionic, mobile

preciso de uma ajuda ou de uma direção, tentarei ser breve, é o seguinte estou desenvolvendo um app para um cliente, e preciso desse app em pouquíssimo tempo por essa razão resolvi não desenvolver por meios comuns, tendo a velocidade em mente escolheram o ionic creator para fazer a "casca" do app, e por meios de botões dentro dessa casca eu redireciono para paginas da web que já estão prontas, usei c# para fazer o meu "Back end", ai que está a minha duvida: gerei uma .apk e quando uso no meu celular e quando clico em um dos botões ele abre uma pagina separadamente no meu navegador ou seja ele sai do app e entra no Browser, o que nós queríamos era algo parecido com o que vimos em apps como: Playstation, Jovem nerd, ign.. um app que pegue links responsivos da web e abra-os dentro do app msm não que entre pelo navegador mesmo.

O que eu posso fazer pessoal?? preciso de uma ajuda...

Comment: Amigo, você poderia ser mais simples e claro... Mas vamos lá! Se você estiver utilizando Ionic, você pode chamar o webview do cordova! $scope.openCordovaWebView = function()
{
  window.open('http://google.com','_self'); 
};

Comment: `estou desenvolvendo um app para um cliente, e preciso desse app em pouquíssimo tempo` Aprenda a não tentar dar passos maior que suas pernas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Adicione a linha abaixo no método sobrescrito OnCreate() da sua aplicação

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

E defina esta classe, ainda dentro do método OnCreate

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Desta maneira, o aplicativo Android deve respeitar o seu WebView e não abrir outros navegadores quando tentar abrir um link.

Total crédito para Framework System, que foi onde encontrei a resposta pra esse problema quando passei por ele também.
http://www.frameworksystem.com/mobile-webview-abrindo-em-um-browser/

Att